# Gulp task for multiple js libraries along with appropiate names

Tags: javascript, gulp

Can anyone pls tell how to write gulp task for files in different folders. ?
I mean

```
www
   js
      a.js
   lib
      jq.js
```

Output:

```
www 
   js
     a.min.js
   lib
     jq.min.js
```

I am unable to write in single task.
I am using rename,obfuscate and ngAnnotate plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Use the array syntax for `gulp.src` as:

```
gulp.task('task-name', function () {
  return gulp.src(['www/js/**/*.js', 'www/lib/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(<Add your task>)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www'));
})
```